# Mouseleave is called before mouseclick when trying to disable onbeforeunload for anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm trying to disable the `onbeforeunload` for all anchor links on my page so it's only triggered when I close the browser window/tab.

Here's how I'm doing this:

For all anchors, `onmouseover`, I store a null value to the `window.onbeforeunload` function. Then, `onmouseleave`, I restore the `window.onbeforeunload` function:

```
$(function () {
    SetupOnNavigateAway();
});

function OnBeforeUnload(oEvent) {       
    return "Are you sure you want to close this page?";     
}

function SetupOnNavigateAway() {
    window.onbeforeunload = OnBeforeUnload;
    $(window).data('beforeunload', window.onbeforeunload);
    $('body').delegate('a', 'hover', function (event) {
        if (event.type === 'mouseenter' || event.type === "mouseover")
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        else
            window.onbeforeunload = $(window).data('beforeunload');
    });
}
```

My problem is that for some browser versions, the `mouseleave` event is triggered before the `mouseclick` event when I click on a link. (My cursor has NOT left the link) So the `onbeforeunload` function is called when it doesn't have to be called..

Example:

This is how it's handled now:

1. move mouse on the button: `window.onbeforeunload = null`
2. move mouse off the button: `window.onbeforeunload = OnBeforeUnload`
3. move mouse on the button: `window.onbeforeunload = null`
4. stay with cursor on the button and click: `window.onbeforeunload = OnBeforeUnload`, redirect

This is how it should work:

1. move mouse on the button: `window.onbeforeunload = null`
2. move mouse off the button: `window.onbeforeunload = OnBeforeUnload`
3. move mouse on the button: `window.onbeforeunload = null`
4. stay with cursor on the button and click: redirect (`window.onbeforeunload` is still null)

So how can I prevent the `mouseleave` event to happen when I click on an anchor?

Comment: Isn't it OnMouseOut? Not mouseleave

Comment: I use firebug, I can see the value of event.type is mouseleave. But it doesn't matter because it's all catched in my 'else' structure. When i click the button, it shoudn't get into to 'hover' function but redirect immediatly to another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to unbind your eventlistener for mouseleave on click:

```
$('body').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
    $(this).unbind('mouseleave'); 
});
```

Comment: That maybe is a good idea. I'm just trying out something else first, then i'll give your answer a try. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: I've updated your answer a bit. I'll check as accepted when it's revised. Your answer works and it demands less code than my other sollution i've also added here. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works for me but for those who may need another sollution, here's what also works for me:

```
$('body').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
    $(this).attr('clicked', 'yes'); 
});
$('body').delegate('a', 'hover', function (event) {
    if (event.type === 'mouseenter' || event.type === "mouseover") {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
    else {
        if ($(this).attr('clicked') != 'yes') {
            window.onbeforeunload = $(window).data('beforeunload');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('clicked', '');
        }
    }
});
```